# Conditional Where Arguments in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table 'Asset' in database. This table has four fields (Id, Name, LocationId, CategoryId).

I want to make a stored procedure which will return the assets based on provided LocationId and CategoryId parameters.

I want to make Where clause optional with respect to LocationId i.e. If user passes LocationId as 0 then I dont want to put restriction on LocationId otherwise I need to put restriction on LocationId also. i.e If @LocationId is 0 then assets from all location ids should be returned.

How can I change following query to achieve this

```
select * from Asset where LocationId = @LocationId and CategoryId = @CategoryId
```

Any Help?

Comment: (LocationId = @@LocationId or @@LocationId = 0)

Comment: single at signs... SO got confused with single 'at's

Comment: Please read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is declare your variables as null at the beginning.

So `@LocationID int = null`

Then in your where clause you'll want to put something like

```
WHERE (LocationID = @LocationID or @LocationID IS NULL)
```

That way if you don't pass an ID, everything will be returned.

EDIT - So this works for you, just make the passing of the ID's optional instead of putting 0's in, you could of course do     `WHERE (LocationID = @LocationID or @LocationID = 0)`

I just think the use of NULL's is much cleaner.

Full Query:

```
CREATE PROC
@LocationID int = 0,
@CategoryID int = 0

AS

SELECT *

FROM
Asset

WHERE
(LocationID = @LocationID or @LocationID = 0)
AND
(ActivityID = @ActivityID or @ActivtyID = 0)
```

Comment: I have wrote the full query for you. Try that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765.aspx) in your `Where` Clause

```
select * from Asset 
where LocationId = Case When @LocationId=0 then LocationId else @LocationId end
and CategoryId = @CategoryId
```

Comment: @Downvoter What is the Problem with my query could you please specify

Comment: There is no need to use a case. It is inefficient.

Comment: @Telexx I had Used `CASE` because in the Question **Bilal Ahmed** said if the @LocationId is 0 then records of all the location will be selected otherwise only a Particular Location records will be selected

Comment: Ok, but it's still unnecessary.. I didn't downvote it either btw, because it still works..